# How to get child URL from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="browsensearch" src="http://facebook.com/" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">
    Your browser does not support IFRAME's
</iframe>
```

When open this web page get the URL `facebook.com` but when change on this link `www.facebook.com/login.php`, I want get the child URL `www.facebook.com`.

Comment: You want to get it where ?

Comment: iframe in  website changed(www.facebook.com) or go to another webpage(www.facebook.com/index.php).

Comment: i want iframe in change URL

Comment: just i take an example.

Comment: like that how to get i frame dynamic change web page URL

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Copy() 
            {
                 urlCopied.innerHTML = window.location.href;
                }
        </script>
<body>
    <div>

        <input type="button" value="Copy Url" onclick="Copy();" />
        <br />

        Paste: <textarea id="urlCopied" rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

try this,wait for 2 seconds and watch the console:

```js
let iframe = document.getElementById('browsensearch');
iframe.onload = function() {
  let url = new URL(this.src);
  console.log(url.hostname);
};

//code below for testing
setTimeout(function() {
  iframe.src = 'https://www.baidu.com';
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
  iframe.src = 'https://baidu.com';
}, 4000);
```

```html
<iframe id="browsensearch" src="https://baidu.com/" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: when search a word in  webpage.

Comment: it is always shows iframe url only but i want iframe in webpage change dynamically. then shows current URL

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>